# Proving with calculus Cobb Douglas Production Function's Returns to Scale

Tags: partial-derivative, economics

**Background and Trivial Proof by "Example"**

The way the Rate of Return for the Cobb Douglas production function is proven in the new definition of my textbook is as follows.

The Cobb Douglas function definition

$ p = AL^aK^b$ $where,$ $(A,a,b)$ $are$ $constant$.

Consider multiplying the inputs Labor $L$ and Capital $K$ by any factor $m$.

$A(mL)^a(mK)^b$

$Am^aL^am^bK^b$

$m^am^bAL^aK^b$

$m^{(a+b)}AL^aK^b$

$m^{(a+b)}p$

From this you can see that the rate of change is dependent on the sum of $a+b$ and it is easy to show the properties of returns to scale as they simply follow the rules of the exponential function. The important properties in terms of economics is that for any positive change in m (means m != 1) the rate of change increases if $a+b>1$ decreases if $a+b<1$ and is equal to the change in m if $a+b=1$

**Problem Statement**

The previous method ignores defining mathematically Returns to Scale. Furthermore, in an older version of my text book it uses some calculus to prove that Returns to Scale equals $a+b$ ... it just sort of skips some steps after the basic differentiation so I can't understand how they arrive at that answer.

**Attempted Solution**

Returns to Scale seems to be the change in the production function. If this is correct it should be equal to the derivative of the production function. Since we have two variables K and L we need to take the partial derivatives and add them together.

$R =\frac{∂P}{∂K} + \frac{∂P}{∂L}$

$R = aAL^{a-1}K^b + bAL^aK^{b-1}$

$R = aAL^aL^{-1}K^b + bAL^aK^bK^{-1}$

$R = AL^aK^b(aK^{-1} + bL^{-1})$

This is where the old edition textbook page I saw did some magic I'm not 100% sure but I think it said divide by p and evaluate at 1 to get $R = a + b$.

**Notes**

I'm not sure how to simplify it any further and ending up with the original function in the derivative confuses me even more. I haven't done partial derivatives in forever though so there may be something I'm just missing about adding partial derivatives.

I'm also confused because from the background proof it would seem that the Returns to Scale are $m^{a+b}$ not a+b.

Comment: On the first line where you write "Rate of Return" do you mean "returns to scale"? You can find a definition of returns to scale on Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Returns_to_scale#Formal_definitions

Comment: Note, that the wikipedia definition you linked to is equivelent to the "trivial proof" in the background section. The wikipedia article is very incomplete and doesn't include the information I was looking for as shown (but not explained) in the accepted answer "returns to scale" is formally defined as the elasticities of the input factors. The "formal proof" on wikipedia is trivial and does not begin from a proper or apropriate definition.

Comment: The "trivial proof" is THE proof of the returns to scale for the Cobb-Douglas production function. The definition of (constant, increasing, decreasing) returns to scale on the Wikipedia page is the standard one. Returns to scale is not usually defined in terms of the elasticities of the input factors (some production functions are not differentiable).

Comment: The accepted answer is not deriving the returns to scale of the Cobb-Douglas production function. Instead, it is hinting at the result for the special case of the Cobb-Douglas production function that the sum of the elasticities is equal to the degree of homogeneity of the Cobb-Douglas production function. (The degree of homoegeneity $a+b$ determines the returns to scale.) More generally, a production function might be nonhomogeneous, but we can still apply the definition to see what type of returns to scale it exhibits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: In the case of the Cobb-Douglas function the return of scale is the sum of the elasticities of the input factors:

$$R=\frac{\partial P}{\partial L}\cdot \frac{L}{P}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial K}\cdot \frac{K}{P}$$

$$=a\cdot A\cdot L^{a-1}K^b\cdot \frac{L}{AL^{a}K^b}+b\cdot A\cdot L^{a}K^{b-1}\cdot \frac{K}{AL^{a}K^b}$$

I think you can finish.